# Printing an uninitialized bool using cout (C++)

Tags: c++, cout, initialization, ostream

I have a class with a `bool` data member that is not initialized by the constructor.  If I do

```
cout << x.myBoolDataMember;
```

where `x` is an object of this class in which the `bool` has not been initialized, I sometimes get a random number rather than 0 or 1.  (I'm using `gcc`.)  Is this behavior compliant with the `Standard`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this behavior compliant with the standard?

Yes! Using garbage values(uninitialized) in your code invokes **Undefined Behavior**

Answer (score 4):

Yes. An uninitialized variable can have any value.

Comment: It is difficult to talk about values in the presence of undefined behavior. `bool` only has two possible values, `false` and `true`. The fact that `cout << b` outputs something other than `0` and `1` is a consequence of the behavior not being defined, not of `b` having a "value" other than `false` or `true`.

Comment: True. It could also print nothing at all, 0.5, "blue", or emit smoke

Comment: You could turn into a cat. Demons could fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as "<<" operator does not check the bool, this behavior is correct.
The problem here is hidden in the bool itself: program uses more than one bit to store the bool. This is dependent on implementation. Sometimes only one bit can be used to store the bool.
Sometimes more, and it is such a case.